# Connect Google Drive to Could SQL

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs-api, google-cloud-sql

I am looking to try and combine Google's Cloud SQL service with google drive.  Essentially I want to use Google forms for the user to easily input data, and then have that data feed into the Cloud SQL environment (from which I can do reporting and analysis).

My question is, has anyone done this already, or have any ideas of how this might be accomplished?  I already have google forms writing to spreadsheets, and that works fine.  I am familiar with SQL so creating reports and pulling data from the Cloud SQL environment shouldn't be hard.....but I don't know how to connect the two.

Ideally I would like something to run on a schedule (maybe on a nightly basis) to pull the data from a google spreadsheet, update the Cloud SQL database, and clear the old data from the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to do this would be to use [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script).

Apps Script allows you, for a given form, to define an `onSubmit()` method that will be called when someone submitted an answer to the form.

Then you can use the `JDBC` service to connect to Cloud SQL.